# How to select interactively datasets to plot with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, visualization

I'm using Manipulate to visualize three datasets:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[WHAT -> what], {what, {dataset1, dataset2, dataset3}}]
```

Now with this solution I can only plot data for either dataset1, dataset2 or dataset3.

What if I wanted to plot the data for BOTH dataset1 and dataset2 on the same graph? Or for all three datasets? An easy way such as checking boxes corresponding to the datasets would be nice, but I don't know how to integrate this with Manipulate.

Comment: please use a meaningful example instead of dummy names

Comment: @rm-rf  Like `WHO -> "is in the first base"`?

Comment: I would say that the title is misleading. I understood it in the way that one wants to pick up several numeric values from a list shown in Manipulate.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch that's what I wanted to do in the first place (see my comment below to Jagra's answer), and the question was clear, but then rm-rf told me to delete dummy names which led to more confusion than originally. Dummy names were there for a good reason, my problem comes from the fact that I work on custom functions, if dummy names are "transparent" (eg "myList") I don't see why we should avoid them?

Comment: At this point, I don't have a clue about what you really want  Clarifying a question helps everyone.  Changing what you want from a question disregards the efforts that people make in producing answers.  Two seeming good answers have come for this question.  I'd recommend accepting the best of them (mine! mine! Mine! ;-) then giving some more thought to formulating and submitting a second question.

Comment: I guess I'll keep my answer... no idea what's actually wanted. Due to the title, maybe somebody might find it useful...

Comment: @Sullivan Orlean I understood the title such that there is a list, say, plotted by ListPlot and the task is to pick up coordinates of few points chosen interactively. If this (or something like this) is the case, I would propose to formulate such a task in a separate question, while leaving this question as it is, since the answers to the present question have value by themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slightly different approach with `Checkbox`es:

```
Manipulate[Module[{dataset},
  dataset = RandomReal[#, 100] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
  ListPlot[dataset[[{x, y, z}]], Joined -> True]
  ], {x, {0, 1}, Checkbox}, {y, {0, 2}, Checkbox}, {z, {0, 3}, 
  Checkbox}]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When x, y, or z are unchecked, they are 0 and `dataset[[0]]` is `List`, so `ListPlot` is passed something like `{List, {0.12, ...}, List}`, which doesn't work.

Comment: @Federico -- Odd.  Works perfectly for me with any and all combinations of the different checkboxes.  I run version 9.  Under what version have you tried this?

Comment: I use version 8. Here is a [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/fq8rxuudt/). The problem is that in version 8 `ListPlot[{_, List, _}]` is not allowed.

Comment: Works OK here with Mathematica 9.0.1 (under OS X 10.8.3) with all three unchecked as well as all 1-box, 2-box, and 3-box combinations tried, too.

Comment: @Federico Thanks it works, but because of rm-rf who told me to rephrase my question, actually what I want to do is a little bit different. Let's imagine I have a custom function like: `Manipulate[
 customFunction[{"myList"}, OPTION -> option], {option, listOfOptions, 
  ControlType -> "SetterBar"}]` , but instead of a SetterBar, I'd like a TogglerBar (allowing me to select multiple values at the same time from listOfOptions ). How would I do that?

Comment: @SullivanOrlean -- If you need backward compatibility with versions 8 and 7 and want to use `TogglerBar`, look at @PinguinDirk's answer and mine.

Comment: @SullivanOrlean -- Note that the correct syntax is `ControlType -> SetterBar` or `ControlType -> TogglerBar`, without quotes.

Comment: To get this code working under version 10.1, one has to removes the `0`'s from the list, e. g., by using `ListPlot[dataset[[DeleteCases[{x, y, z}, 0]]], Joined -> True]`.

Answer (score 8):

With the arbitrary datasets

```
datasets = {dataset1, dataset2, dataset3} = RandomReal[#, 100] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
```

one can pre-render the plots and add an empty plot for the case when no dataset is selected

```
plots = Append[
         MapThread[ListPlot[#1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> #2] &, 
          {datasets, ColorData[97] /@ Range[3]}],
        ListPlot[{}]];
```

A relative intuitive way to interactively select the datasets to be plotted within `Manipulate` can be achieved by creating a clickable line legend. Different control types can be used to achieve this. In my opinion the most unambiguous one is generated using checkboxes

```
Manipulate[Show[plots[[datasetNo /. {} -> 4]], PlotRange -> All],
 {{datasetNo, {1}, ""}, 
  Thread[Range[3] -> MapThread[
   Row[{Pane@Graphics[{#1, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 20], 
    "  Dataset " <> ToString@#2}, BaselinePosition -> Center] &,                     
   {ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], Range[3]}]], 
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar, BaselinePosition -> Center, Method -> "Active", 
  Appearance -> "Vertical"}, ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

> [image: CheckboxLineLegend]

but `ListPicker` and `TogglerBar` give good alternatives, too:

> [image: ListPickerLineLegend]
>
> [image: TogglerLineLegend]

---

## Update: Dimming the inactive line legend items

```
datasetNames = Array["  Dataset " <> ToString@# &, 3]

Manipulate[
 Show[plots[[datasetNo /. {} -> 4]], PlotRange -> All],
 Row[{
  Control[{{datasetNo, {1, 3}, ""}, {1 -> "", 2 -> "", 3 -> ""}, 
   ControlType -> CheckboxBar, BaselinePosition -> Center, 
   Method -> "Active", Appearance -> "Vertical"}], 
  Dynamic@Column[
   MapThread[
    Row[{Pane@
      Graphics[{#1, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 20],
      MapAt[Style[#, Opacity[0.35]] &, datasetNames, 
       List /@ Complement[Range[3], datasetNo]][[#2]]}, 
       BaselinePosition -> Center] &, 
    {MapAt[Opacity[0.1, #] &, ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], 
     List /@ Complement[Range[3], datasetNo]], Range[3]}], 
   Left, 0.9, ItemSize -> {Automatic, 0}, BaselinePosition -> Center]}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

> [image: dimmedInactiveLineLegend]

Comment: Version 9 user can use `ListPlot[{""}]` to generate the empty plot and `ColorData[1]` to get the default colors.

Comment: Clickable line legends!  Great solution +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

here's a guess, is that what you want? (too long for a comment)

```
data = RandomInteger[10, {3, 10}]
```

and then you could do:

```
Manipulate[
ListPlot[what, Joined -> True], {{what, data}, 
MapIndexed[# -> First[#2] &, data], ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

to get:

[image]

**EDIT** (since I still do not know what the OP seeks, I'll keep above)

Based on Federico's comments (thanks!), here's an adjusted version that doesn't break on empty selection and has dedicated colors per "dataset":

```
Manipulate[
 If[what != {},ListPlot[what, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle ->Extract[{Red, Blue, Green}, Position[data, #] & /@ what]], 
 ""], 
 {{what, data}, MapIndexed[# -> First[#2] &, data], 
 ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

Alternatively, to maintain the default colour scheme:

```
data = RandomReal[{#, # + 1}, 24] & /@ Range[5];
Manipulate[
 If[what =!= {},
  ListLinePlot[data[[what]], PlotStyle -> (ColorData[1] /@ what), ImageSize -> {400, 300}],
  Panel[Style["Select some data!", 18, "TI"],
   Alignment -> Center, Background -> White, Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> {400, 300}]],
 {{what, {1}}, Range@Length[data], ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

Comment: Although very nice, clean and concise, there are two issues: 1) an error is displayed if no dataset is selected; 2) plot lines are subject to colour change (try switching everything off, then click 1, 2, 1). Both of them can be easily fixed.

Comment: @Federico: thanks for the input! I wasn't aware that `TogglerBar` appends the most recently selected choice at the end. As you say "easily fixed", feel free to edit my answer incase you have a better approach - I am sure I must've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = RandomReal[{#, # + 1}, 24] & /@ Range[5];
Manipulate[
 If[what =!= {},
  ListLinePlot[data[[what]], PlotStyle -> (ColorData[1] /@ what), ImageSize -> {400, 300}],
  Panel[Style["Select some data!", 18, "TI"],
   Alignment -> Center, Background -> White, Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> {400, 300}]],
 {{what, {1}}, Range@Length[data], ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```