# How to hide and show graphics within Show (in Manipulate)

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphics

There is a well documented way to "Dynamically Hide and Show Plots" ([link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/DynamicallyHideAndShowPlots.html)).
In the example 'Opacity' option is effectively used.
Is there an efficient way to make the same functionality with "Show"?
I can only see a way using `"if"` statement, but it looks somewhat cumbersome as it wants dummy `Graphic[]` as a placeholder.
For instance:

```
Manipulate[    
 a = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}];    
 b = Plot[1 - z, {z, 0, 1}];    
 Show[    
  If[cond1 == 1, a, Graphics[]],
  If[cond2 == 1, b, Graphics[]]
 ],
 Grid[
  {
   {Control[{{cond1, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "a"},
   {Control[{{cond2, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "b"}
  }
 ]    
]
```

Another drawback is that unchecking `'a'` causes `Plot` axes to disappear.
Any ideas?

Comment: Re the "drawback":  use the option `Axes -> True` in `Show`, or use `Graphics[{}, Axes -> True]` instead of  `Graphics[]` inside `If`.

Comment: @kguler, thank you; is there a way to have Axes 'stable' in this case? Plot 'form' changes when 'a' is unchecked (though Axes are in place =))).

Comment: you can also add `PlotRange-> ...` to  `Show` or to the empty `Graphics`.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work for me (AspectRatio does not do the job either)

Comment: garej, `Show[If[cond1 == 1, a, Graphics[]], If[cond2 == 1, b, Graphics[]], 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],` works as expected in version 9.0.1.0 on Windows 8 (64bit).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86230/18476 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86143/18476

Comment: @Karsten7, I've admitted that, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[a = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]; b = Plot[1 - z, {z, 0, 1}];
 Show[If[cond1 == 1, a, Graphics[]], If[cond2 == 1, b, Graphics[]], 
  Axes -> (cond1+cond2>=1), PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
 Grid[{{Control[{{cond1, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "a"}, 
       {Control[{{cond2, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "b"}}]]
```

[image]

Change `Axes -> (cond1 + cond2 >= 1)` to `Axes->True` if you want to have the axes always visible.

You can get the same result by changing the `PlotStyle` of plots `a` and `b` based on the `cond1` and `cond2`, respectivly.

```
Manipulate[ a = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> If[cond1 == 0, Opacity[0], Opacity[1]]];
 b = Plot[1 - z, {z, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> If[cond2 == 0, Opacity[0], Opacity[1]]];
 Show[a, b, Axes -> (cond1+cond2>=1), PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
 Grid[{{Control[{{cond1, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "a"},
       {Control[{{cond2, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "b"}}]]
```

Alternatively, use a single plot with two curves:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {If[cond1 == 0, Opacity[0], Opacity[1]], 
                 If[cond2 == 0, Opacity[0], Opacity[1]]},
   Axes -> (cond1+cond2>=1), PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
 Grid[{{Control[{{cond1, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "a"}, 
       {Control[{{cond2, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "b"}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you have to use `Show`:

```
Manipulate[ab = Plot[{x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {If[cond1 == 0, Opacity[0], Opacity[1]], 
     If[cond2 == 0, Opacity[0], Opacity[1]]}];
 Show[ab, Axes -> (cond1 + cond2 >= 1), PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], 
 Grid[{{Control[{{cond1, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "a"},
       {Control[{{cond2, 1, ""}, {0, 1}}], "b"}}]]
```