# How can I add a vertical spacing in a `CheckboxBar`?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, grid-layouts, spacing, user-interface

I have an [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86135/listplot-with-checkboxes) here from the solution of @krasten 7. In this I would like some vertical spacing between the checkboxes. Any ideas?

```
prjs = {prj1, prj2, prj3} = RandomReal[#, 100] & /@ {1, 2, 3};

Manipulate[ListPlot[prjs[[projectNo]], Joined -> True], 
 {{projectNo, {1}}, Range[Length@prjs], ControlType -> CheckboxBar,Appearance -> 
"Vertical", ControlPlacement -> Right }]
```

In addition to it, I am also looking for more control options like checkbox size or relative postions. Appreciate your time. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wrap `CheckboxBar` with [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) using the option [`DefaultOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultOptions.html) to modify the `Spacings` option of `Grid` objects:

```
ClearAll[addVerticalSpace]
addVerticalSpace[vs_: .3] := 
 Style[#, DefaultOptions -> {Grid -> {Spacings -> {Automatic, vs}}}] &
```

***Examples:***

```
cbb = CheckboxBar[{1}, Range[4], Appearance -> "Vertical"];

Row[{cbb, 
  addVerticalSpace[] @ cbb, 
  addVerticalSpace[0] @ cbb, 
  addVerticalSpace[1] @ cbb, 
  addVerticalSpace[2] @ cbb}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
prjs = RandomReal[#, 100] & /@ {1, 2, 3};

addVerticalSpace[2] @
 Manipulate[ListPlot[prjs[[projectNo]], Joined -> True], 
 {{projectNo, {1}}, Range[Length@prjs], ControlType -> CheckboxBar, 
   Appearance -> "Vertical", ControlPlacement -> Right}]
```

[image]

Comment: you are amazing!!

Answer (score 6):

```
prjs = {prj1, prj2, prj3} =
   RandomReal[#, 100] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
```

To widen the spacing of the checkboxes, you can use multi-row labels with the extra rows empty.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[prjs[[projectNo]],
  Joined -> True],
 {{projectNo, {1}, "Project\nNumber"},
  (# -> StringForm["``\n\n\n", #]) & /@
   Range[Length@prjs],
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar,
  Appearance -> "Vertical",
  ControlPlacement -> Right}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon, it's much simpler

Answer (score 5):

You can also wrap labels with `Pane` and use the option `ImageSize` to control the vertical span of labels:

```
ClearAll[paneWrap]
paneWrap[vSize_: 20] := Map[# -> Pane[#, Alignment -> Center, 
   BaselinePosition -> Baseline, ImageSize -> {Automatic, vSize}] &]
```

***Examples:***

```
prjs = RandomReal[#, 100] & /@ {1, 2, 3};

Row[{CheckboxBar[{1}, Range[Length @ prjs], Appearance -> "Vertical"],
  CheckboxBar[{1}, paneWrap[] @ Range[Length @ prjs], Appearance -> "Vertical"],
  CheckboxBar[{1}, paneWrap[30] @ Range[Length @ prjs], Appearance -> "Vertical"]}, 
  Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[prjs[[projectNo]], Joined -> True], 
 {{projectNo, {1}}, paneWrap[75] @ Range[Length @ prjs],
   ControlType -> CheckboxBar, Appearance -> "Vertical", ControlPlacement -> Right}]
```

[image]